# Export CSV via Javascript - Can export in Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, csv, google-chrome, firefox

As my title, I have researched many of threads but I didn't solve my problem.

```
function DownloadCSV(obj = null, filename = null){
    var data = obj;
    var csv = ConvertToCSV(data); //Don't mind, my data are good, I checked it.
    var fileName = filename;

    if (navigator.userAgent.search("Firefox") >= 0) {
      //For firefox
        var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
        downloadLink.setAttribute("href", "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,%EF%BB%BF" + encodeURI(csv));
        downloadLink.setAttribute("download", ""+fileName+".csv");
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
        downloadLink.click();

    } else {
       //For chrome
        var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
        downloadLink.setAttribute("href", "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,%EF%BB%BF" + encodeURI(csv));
        downloadLink.setAttribute("download", ""+fileName+".csv");
        downloadLink.click();
    }
}
```

**Note:** My data are Asia characters that contain UTF8 charset.

**Issue:** My code was perfect working in Chrome, I can download the CSV file and open it in Excel correctly; but it's error in Firefox and IE10.

In Firefox, I also can download the files, but it was not CSV extension. It was something like "r1ruu9fa.part" instead of "Test.csv". My data in this .part file was correct. It's only the file extension was not correct.

I tried to debug the "downloadLink" variable in Firefox, I saw my file name was still "Test.csv" but when click download, it was changed.

**Question:** So what am I missing in config the variable "downloadLink"?

Comment: I've found [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) library takes the guess work out of doing exactly what you want

Comment: I take a look for description of these. I thank that more easy than mine. I will try it to my project and let you know the result. Thank you.